# How to add product into cart and get it into list view in another activity

Tags: android, json, api

I am getting data from json in listview, when i click on listview item it will open another activity with item details. In this activity i have button add-to-cart. After click on add-to-cart button i want to push that product cart activity

[This is my list view, In listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZCxq.png)

[This is my details activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6A7NA.png)

Now after click On add_to_cart button i want to push this product in to cart. How can i do this.

Comment: Adding product to cart is nothing just storing the product into database until user buy that product or cancel the product

Comment: Use Sqlite or Realm db for storing products in cart. Create table Cart with product id, qty and other attributes.

Comment: How you got that far without understanding java objects is beyond me, but you want some central data structure that can be updated from all of your screens with products or "add to cart" and then you just want to put this into an adapter of some sort and attach it to a listview or recycler view. People before me mentioned DBs, that sounds like a plan if you want your user to persist their carts, but if you want it to disappear when they close the app, you could probably just store it in memory. I would say you should look up 'how to add a cart to android app' and you'll see lots of ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you would like to fire event in somewhere and there is actions will receive it and then do its stuff . 
you can use listeners , RXjava , Eventbus 
I guess in your case the easy way will be Eventbus

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

just create your event like `DeleteProductEvent` then post it with 
`EventBus.getDefault().post(new DeleteProductEvent());`
then you can handle it in your list activity by 

`@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)

public void onMessageEvent(DeleteProductEvent event) {*handle what do you want *};`